# Why there's no output generated?

Tags: php, html

What wrong with my code? `uniqid()` is for generating a unique code and it will be stored to the name attribute then a condition is stated if it is clicked it will generate it's working.. Could some help me please with this one? Thanks in advance..

```
 <html>
    <form method="POST">


    <?php

    $attname = uniqid();

    echo "<input type='submit' name='$attname' class='btn btn-success' value='Post to Peónline'/>";
    echo $attname;
    if(isset($_POST[$attname])){
    echo 'its working';
    }
    ?>
    </form>

    <html>
```

Comment: the input name should be like this name ="uniqid" or name ="uniqid[]"

$attname = uniqid;

Comment: Add more code. It is not clear.

Comment: @Ramki so what is wrong with that now?

Comment: Do you have opening <form> tag?

Comment: Do you have <form opening tag? Where action points to?

Comment: @Pupil sorry about may form tag.. I forgot to indent my code.. but still it's not working

Comment: @Ramki I use to generate a short hash for may attribute name.. any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't going to work.

When you refresh the page the `$attname` value will change. This will happen when you submit the form. So the actual name you're checking on will change and not be the same as the new `$attname`.

**Put the following after your `echo $attname;` line:**

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Also for this to work properly you'll need to nest the `<input>` tag in a `<form>` tag e.g.:

```
<form method="POST">
<input>...</input>
</form>
```

Comment: is there another way to do this?

Comment: You'll need to store the ID in a database or something and then have to get it out of the database when the page is reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

The `$attname` will change after page refresh.

You need to store that name somewhere.

Add another hidden element.

```
...
echo "<input type='hidden' name='elemname' value='<?php echo $attname;?>'/>";
...
```

And after submit,

```
if (isset($_POST['elemname'])) {
  $elemname = $_POST['elemname'];
  $val = isset($_POST[$elemname]) ? $_POST[$elemname] : '';
  echo $val;
}
```